# Where can I find list with web-safe fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts, frontend

Basing on your experience in frontend and web applications, can you provide good and solid source or list with web-safe fonts? Or any other good tool ensuring font safety in web browsers?

Most of the time I was using [Squirrel Fonts](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) but a lot of fonts, which my designers use, are blocked there and the only way I can show them are PNGs.

Comment: `serif`, `sans-serif`, `monospace`

Comment: @NiftyDude, those are not font names but generic names that browser will map to whatever they like. So these names are guaranteed to be non-safe, if safety means getting your text rendered in a specific font with some kind of certainty.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I understand, hence it's not an answer, rather a comment. I'm just implying there's no such thing as `web-safe` fonts, it solely depends on your clients

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no absolute safety, unless you're going with generic classes like "serif", "sans-serif" etc.

Here are some resources that can give you an idea about the most prevalent fonts:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20160610001431/http://www.awayback.com/revised-font-stack/
- http://cssfontstack.com/

You'll see that no single font exists on all operating systems. The best thing you can do is to use a **font stack** that covers the greatest percentage and hope for the best. Using a sensible font stack is the way to go...

Comment: Sure, no single font exists on all operating systems, but a **web browser** like Chrome could ensure that at least a set of free fonts are reliably present if it wants to. Pity that it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can generator font from here also http://www.font2web.com/ & you can use Google fonts also http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive list of web safe fonts that I have found. The research gave me some basic idea but then I had to experiment on my own machines. I wanted something that would work on Windows, Mac, and Linux machines. Luckily I had one of each.

There are 5 types of fonts recognized by HTML, namely serif, sans-serif, monospace, fantasy, and cursive. However, I see 6 types myself, being as cursive breaks down into scripts and handwritten fonts in my mind. What I came up with for 'web safe' font stacks is as follows:

```
/* Web Safe Font Stacks */
.head { font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', serif; } /* H1-H6 */
.para { font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; } /* Paragraphs, body text */
.mono { font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace; } /* code, pre, etc. */
.fant { font-family: Papyrus, Impact, fantasy; } /* Fantasy */
.curs { font-family:'Apple Chancery', 'Lucida Calligraphy', cursive; } /* Cursive */
.hand { font-family:'Comic Sans MS', Chalkboard, cursive; } /* Handwritten */
```

I hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

The list of “safe” fonts, if that means a list of font names that will give you the desired rendering in all situations, or even in almost all situations, is exactly the empty list.

Most purported lists of “web-safe fonts” fail immediately if you test them on Android, for example.

If you actually meant to ask about the problems of using embedded fonts (with `@font face`), I suggest that you check the previous questions and answers on them first.